# Tag Synonym Request: pictures -> images

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was in the process of creating a question on SR and was about to add the tag 'pictures' when I thought, let me check if there is a tag for [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images), which sure enough there was.

So then it got me thinking that most people that don't work with raw graphical data, which is what I consider to be an *image* would probably use/create a tag called pictures; however, no matter what my belief is, I can easily see that the majority may consider an image to be a picture, and vice versa.

So, with the help of someone that has earned the privilege of creating tag synonyms, could we please avoid this confusion in the future by creating a tag synonym of 'pictures' that points to [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)?

However, if you guys do see that these should be kept separate, please let me know so that I can update my question as needed.

Comment: Earlier we thought that [tag:images] might be too ambiguous: it could mean pictures, or things like disk images. See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/private-beta-cleanup-tag-synonyms-and-tag-merges/506#506, http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/private-beta-cleanup-tag-synonyms-and-tag-merges/492#492 and also [What to do with the graphics tag?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/731/what-to-do-with-the-graphics-tag) We need to decide which name we're going with, then we'll synonymize or not depending on what we've decided.

Comment: Thank you for the info @Gilles, I'll read up on those posts later today. I'm hoping we can get this resolved to get something in place before it becomes an issue.  Cheers.

Comment: As a rule, stack exchange doesn't create tag synonyms preemptivly. There are exceptions though.
Reference: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/tag-request-god-machine-rules-update